# Installing pandas on google compute

Tags: python, pandas, google-compute-engine

I tried installing pandas on a linux google compute using

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

but received a number of errors.

I discovered [this helpful link](https://github.com/svaksha/PyData-Workshop-Sprint/wiki/linux-install-pandas).

I got to:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But get back:

```
Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/_libs/period.c' not found.
                Cython is required to compile pandas from a development branch.
                Please install Cython or download a release package of pandas.
```

Going off this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3785) I ran:

```
python ci/print_versions.py
```

and get back:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: 7b8a6b1bc22f6fc0023c02ac8301e07b4ab80417
python: 2.7.9.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.16.0-4-amd64
machine: x86_64
processor:
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: None
pytest: None
pip: 1.5.6
setuptools: 5.5.1
Cython: 0.21.1
numpy: 1.8.2
scipy: None
xarray: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None
patsy: None
dateutil: None
pytz: None
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
feather: None
matplotlib: None
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: None
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

Which indicates that pandas actually sees my Cython.

Would anyone be able to shed some light here?

This is on a micro google compute engine remote linux.

Thanks!